# Flickering random white points / lines on black shadows / textures

Tags: technical-issues, graphics-card

I have a problem that's never occurred before. In the majority of games, part of textures are flickering and some weird white points / lines are randomly appearing on black textures. I already reinstalled the drivers, etc. but it didn't help.

Do you have any idea what it could be? Do I have to reinstall the whole system?

I have a laptop with i7, 8gb ram,  radeon 5850 mobility  and 7200 rpm hdd's.

UPDATE:
this is the video, so you know how it looks like:

Anyways, you have you set the youtube video settings at HD at least, below 720p it is blended. I recommend 1080p

Comment: sounds to me like your card may have been damaged in some way.  Try opening up the CCC and turning off catalyst AI and/or most of the advanced features and see if this still happens.

Comment: Well I just checked the Starcraft II and it is the only game running smoothly without any problems. So the graphic card shouldn't be damage, so what do you think?

Comment: i try to reinstall directx, perhaps those games using it suffer from that problem

Comment: the question is, how to reinstall the directx..

Comment: @ivan: not sure that you can anymore. As of DX10/Vista, DX is pretty tightly integrated into Windows to the point that I'm pretty sure you can't uninstall it.

Answer (score 3):

Symptoms like these can sometimes be caused by overheating.

You may be able to diagnose this by "cold-starting" a game.  Leave your computer completely off (no sleep/suspend mode, though hibernate is fine) for several hours, say overnight.  When you turn in back on, immediately start a game and see whether the symptoms are lessened/abated until the computer warms up.  If so, it's very likely an overheating issue.

In either case, it's probably worth doing a bit of "Spring" cleaning.  Grab a can of compressed air, open any customer-serviceable sections of the computer (often, the keyboard, battery, and sometimes memory or HD slots) and give everything a few good blasts.  Pay particular attention to any exhaust vents, which you'll usually find around sides of the laptop and sometimes on the bottom as well.

Comment: Couldn't it be that some pixel shaders on the graphic card are dead?

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me — Hardware damage is another possibility, yes. Whether or not pixel shaders *specifically* are involved is beyond my knowledge of the inner workings of video cards. :-)